# Why does the tikz library `graphs` not work for me?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

My code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph [nodes={draw, circle}, clockwise, radius=.75cm, empty nodes, n=8] {
            subgraph C_n [name=inner] <->[shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt]
            subgraph C_n [name=outer]
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces the following figure:

[image]

instead of the intended figure:

[image]

Why could this be?

Comment: Right, that's peculiar, as your code is a straight copy from ch. 19 in the pgfmanual. I tried the subgraph example above it, which doesn't work either, while the simple abcd graph does work. I.e. once subgraph is involved, it's "mad".

Comment: You should load `\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}`. In don't know why this is not stated in the manual.

Comment: @JasperHabicht good catch. There is a cryptic warning if you don't add that library... `Package pgf Warning: Returning node center instead of a point on node border. Did you specify a point identical to the center of node ``subgraph C_n''? on input line 12.`

Comment: I just opened a git issue.

Answer (score 9):

There seems to be a mistake in the manual, since the libraray `graphs.standard` is needed for this to work:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph [nodes={draw, circle}, clockwise, radius=.75cm, empty nodes, n=8] {
            subgraph C_n [name=inner] <->[shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt]
            subgraph C_n [name=outer]
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that this is not the only case where the libraries stated in the example are not sufficient. The issue is known and currently being addressed by the package maintainers.